# Use fully qualified table names for Database Projects, Unresolved reference error

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, database-project

I have an existing very large database (several hundred tables) for which I am using a database project in VS 2017.  Consider a UDF as simple as

```
create function [MySchema].fn_Name --MySchema is located in MyDbName
(
   @num int
)
returns table
as return
select @num
inner join [MyDbName].dbo.MyTable mt
on mt.num = @num
```

I have a database project for MyDbName and several tables that are pertinent to this particular project, but those tables do NOT include MyTable.  If I want to use fully qualified names, how can I prevent the ambiguous reference error (SQL71561) for MyTable?  Do I have to explicitly add all of the tables that My procs and functions reference into my database project?

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to understand your question exactly, but there could be several scenarios:

1. If you have a single Database project (`MyDbName`), and both table and the UDF exists there, you should not be using fully qualified name, as you are referencing itself then it makes no sense. There could be a scenario where you have multiple instances of same structure database and one serves as master others as slave, but as I understand this is not the case then simply do not use database name in the statement.
2. If dbo.MyTable exists in different Database project than UDF then you need to add database reference and use variable to define database. [Read more](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj684584(v=vs.103).aspx). Database reference is added by referencing the `.dacpac` of other database project. Then your query would look something like this:

```sql
inner join [$(MyDbName)].dbo.MyTable mt
```

**To answer your question:** No, you don't have to add the tables themselves, but you need to add a reference to a projects which holds those tables.